# Laravel Custom FormRequest in PHPUnit env

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.8, laravel-5.7

Okay so, I've tried searching for a while now for solutions on how and why this is happening, here it goes.

On production environment, this chunk of code works just fine.

```
public function store(Add $request) {
        $data = $request->validated();
        //....  some other stuff
}
```

`Add` is a class that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`, it has some rules only (that I've checked and doesn't influence the error, being the reason for not being posted)

On my test schema, I've got a couple scenarios, mostly Acceptence tests to make sure everything is created (or not) according to different data input. These make calls such as `$this->call($uri, $body, $headers)` and they work as expected, simulating the production environment.

However, I'm trying to write a test specific to the Controller and it keeps on giving me this error:

```
$userController = new UserController();
$request = Add::create('/test', 'POST', $body);
$userController->store($request);
```

This outputs an error:

```
 Error: Call to a member function validated() on null
 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php:188
```

I've tried to output what `dd($request->validated());` returns but this is where it crashes.

1. What is the solution?
2. Why it happens?

Comment: `$this->call($uri, $body, $headers)` The second parameter is the `$body` but you are passing the method of the form in `Add::create('/test', 'POST', $body);`. Maybe this could be the issue?

Comment: $this->call is a laravel testcase function to call URIs with http,  Add::create is a class derivant of FormRequest that represents the body of a HTTP request, they're different things

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new instance of the request there are some properties set to `null`, you will have to populate the `container`, `redirector` and `validator` yourself before you can use the request properly in the controller.

Something like this should work:

```
$userController = new UserController();

// create the request and set the container and redirector
$request = Add::create('/test', 'POST', $body)
    ->setContainer($this->app)
    ->setRedirector($this->app['redirect']);

// resolve the validator
$request->validateResolved();

$userController->store($request);
```